# Linking cURL in C++

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

After trying this for all of today with no result, and searching through LOTS of threads on here and on forums, I'm hoping someone here will be able to find a solution.

I'm trying to get [this simple example using cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simple.html) to work on Windows using MinGW.

When I try to compile it with g++

```
g++ -o Test.exe Test.cpp -DCURL_STATICLIB -I curl\include -L curl\lib -lcurl
```

it always gives me the same errors:

```
C:\Users\Xenon\AppData\Local\Temp\ccI5UUEq.o:Test.cpp:(.text+0x87): undefined reference to `_curl_easy_init'
C:\Users\Xenon\AppData\Local\Temp\ccI5UUEq.o:Test.cpp:(.text+0xb6): undefined reference to `_curl_easy_setopt'
C:\Users\Xenon\AppData\Local\Temp\ccI5UUEq.o:Test.cpp:(.text+0xc2): undefined reference to `_curl_easy_perform'
C:\Users\Xenon\AppData\Local\Temp\ccI5UUEq.o:Test.cpp:(.text+0xd9): undefined reference to `_curl_easy_strerror'
C:\Users\Xenon\AppData\Local\Temp\ccI5UUEq.o:Test.cpp:(.text+0x101): undefined reference to `_curl_easy_cleanup'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

To be honest, I'm all out of ideas what could be causing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
When adding the parameter -v, I'm getting the following output:

```
g++ -v -o Test.exe Test.cpp -DCURL_STATICLIB -I curl\include -L curl\lib -lcurl
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-4.7.0/configure --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --enable-shared --enable-libgomp --disable-win32-registry --enable-libstdcxx-debug --disable-build-poststage1-with-cxx --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --build=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.7.0 (GCC)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'Test.exe' '-D' 'CURL_STATICLIB' '-I' 'curl\include' '-Lcurl\lib' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=i386' '-march=i386'
 c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/cc1plus.exe -quiet -v -I curl\include
 -iprefix c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/ -D CURL_STATICLIB Test.cpp -quiet -dumpbase Test.cpp -mtune=i386 -march=i386 -auxbase Test -version -o C:\Users\Xenon\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsSlqnP.s
GNU C++ (GCC) version 4.7.0 (mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.7.0, GMP version 5.0.1, MPFR version 2.4.1,
MPC version 0.8.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../mingw32/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/mingw32"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/backward"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/mingw/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../mingw32/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/mingw/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 curl\include
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/mingw32
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/backward
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/include
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../include
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/include-fixed
End of search list.
GNU C++ (GCC) version 4.7.0 (mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.7.0, GMP version 5.0.1, MPFR version 2.4.1, MPC version 0.8.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 9fc40f37d31a03e5502141ce58bdf4c7
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'Test.exe' '-D' 'CURL_STATICLIB' '-I' 'curl\include' '-Lcurl\lib' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=i386' '-march=i386'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/as.exe -o C:\Users\Xenon\AppData\Local\Temp\ccYxunOQ.o C:\Users\Xenon\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsSlqnP.s
COMPILER_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/;c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../mingw32/lib/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/../../../
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'Test.exe' '-D' 'CURL_STATICLIB' '-I' 'curl\include' '-Lcurl\lib' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=i386' '-march=i386'
 c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/collect2.exe -Bdynamic -u ___register_frame_info -u ___deregister_frame_info -o Test.exe c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/../../../crt2.o c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/crtbegin.o -Lcurl\lib -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0 -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../mingw32/lib -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/../../.. C:\Users\Xenon\AppData\Local\Temp\ccYxunOQ.o -lcurl -lstdc++ -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -ladvapi32 -lshell32
 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/crtend.o
C:\Users\Xenon\AppData\Local\Temp\ccYxunOQ.o:Test.cpp:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `_curl_easy_init'
C:\Users\Xenon\AppData\Local\Temp\ccYxunOQ.o:Test.cpp:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `_curl_easy_setopt'
C:\Users\Xenon\AppData\Local\Temp\ccYxunOQ.o:Test.cpp:(.text+0x42): undefined reference to `_curl_easy_perform'
C:\Users\Xenon\AppData\Local\Temp\ccYxunOQ.o:Test.cpp:(.text+0x59): undefined reference to `_curl_easy_strerror'
C:\Users\Xenon\AppData\Local\Temp\ccYxunOQ.o:Test.cpp:(.text+0x81): undefined reference to `_curl_easy_cleanup'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I still don't know what could be causing my problem though...are all those "ignored" directories normal?

**Edit:** After now using a 32-bit cURL library, the compiler is literally spamming error messages. I don't know if it means it's working or even more broken now... Had to remove a few messages, as they were 506 lines...

```
>g++ -o Test.exe Test.cpp -DCURL_STATICLIB -I curl\include -L curl\lib -lcurl
curl\lib/libcurl.a(easy.o):(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `_WSAStartup@8'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(easy.o):(.text+0x39): undefined reference to `_WSACleanup@0'
[...]
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x1662): undefined reference to `_BN_num_bits'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x1688): undefined reference to `_BN_num_bits'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x16cb): undefined reference to `_BN_num_bits'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x16f7): undefined reference to `_BN_num_bits'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x1723): undefined reference to `_BN_num_bits'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x174f): more undefined references to `_BN_num_bits' follow
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x1833): undefined reference to `_BN_bn2bin'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x1876): undefined reference to `_BN_num_bits'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x18a2): undefined reference to `_BN_num_bits'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x18ce): undefined reference to `_BN_num_bits'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x18fa): undefined reference to `_BN_num_bits'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x192a): undefined reference to `_BN_num_bits'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x195a): undefined reference to `_BN_bn2bin'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x199a): undefined reference to `_BN_num_bits'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x19c6): undefined reference to `_BN_num_bits'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x19f2): undefined reference to `_BN_num_bits'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x1a22): undefined reference to `_BN_num_bits'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x1a52): undefined reference to `_BN_bn2bin'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x1ade): undefined reference to `_BN_bn2bin'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x1b22): undefined reference to `_BN_bn2bin'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x1b66): undefined reference to `_BN_bn2bin'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x1baa): undefined reference to `_BN_bn2bin'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x1bee): more undefined references to `_BN_bn2bin' follow
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x1e8c): undefined reference to `_GENERAL_NAMES_free'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x1ea0): undefined reference to `_X509_get_subject_name'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x1eca): undefined reference to `_X509_NAME_get_index_by_NID'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x1ee2): undefined reference to `_X509_NAME_get_entry'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x1eea): undefined reference to `_X509_NAME_ENTRY_get_data'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x1efc): undefined reference to `_ASN1_STRING_type'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x1f15): undefined reference to `_ASN1_STRING_to_UTF8'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x1f7f): undefined reference to `_CRYPTO_free'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x1f96): undefined reference to `_X509_free'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x203f): undefined reference to `_ASN1_STRING_data'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x2052): undefined reference to `_ASN1_STRING_length'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x20e0): undefined reference to `_PEM_read_X509'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x2105): undefined reference to `_X509_check_issued'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x213e): undefined reference to `_X509_free'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x2146): undefined reference to `_X509_free'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x21c6): undefined reference to `_X509_free'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x2274): undefined reference to `_X509_free'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x2280): undefined reference to `_X509_free'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x22b4): more undefined references to `_X509_free' follow
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x22c3): undefined reference to `_SSL_get_verify_result'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x233e): undefined reference to `_GENERAL_NAMES_free'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x23b7): undefined reference to `_ASN1_STRING_length'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x23dc): undefined reference to `_CRYPTO_malloc'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x23ec): undefined reference to `_ASN1_STRING_data'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x2467): undefined reference to `_X509_verify_cert_error_string'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x248e): undefined reference to `_X509_verify_cert_error_string'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x24c9): undefined reference to `_GENERAL_NAMES_free'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x251a): undefined reference to `_RAND_load_file'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x251f): undefined reference to `_RAND_status'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x256a): undefined reference to `_RAND_add'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x2578): undefined reference to `_RAND_status'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x2599): undefined reference to `_RAND_file_name'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x25b2): undefined reference to `_RAND_load_file'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x25b7): undefined reference to `_RAND_status'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x267f): undefined reference to `_ERR_clear_error'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x268a): undefined reference to `_SSL_connect'
[...]
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x3ecb): undefined reference to `_RAND_bytes'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ftp.o):(.text+0xdac): undefined reference to `_bind@12'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ftp.o):(.text+0xdbc): undefined reference to `_WSAGetLastError@0'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ftp.o):(.text+0xdfc): undefined reference to `_htons@4'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ftp.o):(.text+0xe4f): undefined reference to `_getsockname@12'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ftp.o):(.text+0xe5f): undefined reference to `_WSAGetLastError@0'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ftp.o):(.text+0xf2d): undefined reference to `_getsockname@12'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ftp.o):(.text+0xf51): undefined reference to `_WSAGetLastError@0'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ftp.o):(.text+0xfb4): undefined reference to `_getsockname@12'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ftp.o):(.text+0xfc4): undefined reference to `_WSAGetLastError@0'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ftp.o):(.text+0x10d1): undefined reference to `_listen@8'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ftp.o):(.text+0x10dd): undefined reference to `_WSAGetLastError@0'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ftp.o):(.text+0x11e9): undefined reference to `_ntohs@4'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ftp.o):(.text+0x1249): undefined reference to `_ntohs@4'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ftp.o):(.text+0x1429): undefined reference to `_getsockname@12'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ftp.o):(.text+0x1478): undefined reference to `_accept@12'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ftp.o):(.text+0x2bb9): undefined reference to `_WSAGetLastError@0'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(telnet.o):(.text+0x3fc): undefined reference to `_WSAStartup@8'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(telnet.o):(.text+0x432): undefined reference to `_WSACleanup@0'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(telnet.o):(.text+0xe1b): undefined reference to `_WSAGetLastError@0'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(telnet.o):(.text+0xe41): undefined reference to `_WSAGetLastError@0'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(telnet.o):(.text+0xf11): undefined reference to `_WSAGetLastError@0'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(telnet.o):(.text.unlikely+0x17b): undefined reference to `_send@16'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(telnet.o):(.text.unlikely+0x18b): undefined reference to `_WSAGetLastError@0'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(telnet.o):(.text.unlikely+0x3bb): undefined reference to `_ntohs@4'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(telnet.o):(.text.unlikely+0x3cb): undefined reference to `_ntohs@4'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(telnet.o):(.text.unlikely+0x5bd): undefined reference to `_htons@4'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(telnet.o):(.text.unlikely+0x5d2): undefined reference to `_htons@4'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(telnet.o):(.text.unlikely+0x6ae): undefined reference to `_send@16'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(telnet.o):(.text.unlikely+0x6ba): undefined reference to `_WSAGetLastError@0'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(telnet.o):(.text.unlikely+0x708): undefined reference to `_send@16'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(telnet.o):(.text.unlikely+0x714): undefined reference to `_WSAGetLastError@0'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(telnet.o):(.text.unlikely+0x853): undefined reference to `_send@16'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(telnet.o):(.text.unlikely+0x85f): undefined reference to `_WSAGetLastError@0'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(telnet.o):(.text.unlikely+0x9ad): undefined reference to `_send@16'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(telnet.o):(.text.unlikely+0x9b9): undefined reference to `_WSAGetLastError@0'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ldap.o):(.text+0x221): undefined reference to `__imp__ldap_err2stringA'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ldap.o):(.text+0x267): undefined reference to `__imp__ldap_msgfree'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ldap.o):(.text+0x298): undefined reference to `__imp__ldap_unbind_s'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ldap.o):(.text+0x6cb): undefined reference to `__imp__ldap_set_optionA'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ldap.o):(.text+0x721): undefined reference to `__imp__ldap_simple_bind_sA'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ldap.o):(.text+0x778): undefined reference to `__imp__ldap_search_sA'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ldap.o):(.text+0x796): undefined reference to `__imp__ldap_err2stringA'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ldap.o):(.text+0x825): undefined reference to `__imp__ldap_err2stringA'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ldap.o):(.text+0x888): undefined reference to `__imp__ldap_set_optionA'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ldap.o):(.text+0x8a3): undefined reference to `__imp__ldap_initA'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ldap.o):(.text+0x8dd): undefined reference to `__imp__ldap_first_entry'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ldap.o):(.text+0x91e): undefined reference to `__imp__ldap_get_dnA'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ldap.o):(.text+0x9bd): undefined reference to `__imp__ldap_first_attributeA'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ldap.o):(.text+0x9e9): undefined reference to `__imp__ldap_get_values_lenA'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ldap.o):(.text+0xbc9): undefined reference to `__imp__ldap_value_free_len'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ldap.o):(.text+0xc1e): undefined reference to `__imp__ldap_memfreeA'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ldap.o):(.text+0xc3d): undefined reference to `__imp__ldap_next_attributeA'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ldap.o):(.text+0xc56): undefined reference to `__imp__ldap_memfreeA'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ldap.o):(.text+0xc71): undefined reference to `__imp__ber_free'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ldap.o):(.text+0xc86): undefined reference to `__imp__ldap_next_entry'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ldap.o):(.text+0xcaf): undefined reference to `__imp__ldap_value_free_len'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ldap.o):(.text+0xcbc): undefined reference to `__imp__ldap_memfreeA'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ldap.o):(.text+0xccb): undefined reference to `__imp__ldap_memfreeA'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ldap.o):(.text+0xcea): undefined reference to `__imp__ber_free'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(tftp.o):(.text+0x210): undefined reference to `_sendto@24'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(tftp.o):(.text+0x29b): undefined reference to `_sendto@24'
[...]
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssh.o):(.text+0x46a9): undefined reference to `_libssh2_knownhost_init'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(ssh.o):(.text+0x46cd): undefined reference to `_libssh2_knownhost_readfile'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(curl_rtmp.o):(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `_RTMP_Close'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(curl_rtmp.o):(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `_RTMP_Free'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(curl_rtmp.o):(.text+0xbc): undefined reference to `_setsockopt@20'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(curl_rtmp.o):(.text+0xcf): undefined reference to `_RTMP_Connect1'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(curl_rtmp.o):(.text+0x13d): undefined reference to `_RTMP_Write'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(curl_rtmp.o):(.text+0x15e): undefined reference to `_RTMP_Alloc'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(curl_rtmp.o):(.text+0x16c): undefined reference to `_RTMP_Init'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(curl_rtmp.o):(.text+0x17c): undefined reference to `_RTMP_SetBufferMS'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(curl_rtmp.o):(.text+0x190): undefined reference to `_RTMP_SetupURL'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(curl_rtmp.o):(.text+0x1ac): undefined reference to `_RTMP_Free'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(curl_rtmp.o):(.text+0x1eb): undefined reference to `_RTMP_Read'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(curl_rtmp.o):(.text+0x24e): undefined reference to `_RTMP_ConnectStream'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(select.o):(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `_WSASetLastError@4'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(select.o):(.text+0x2ae): undefined reference to `_select@20'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(select.o):(.text+0x2bd): undefined reference to `_WSAGetLastError@0'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(select.o):(.text+0x354): undefined reference to `___WSAFDIsSet@8'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(select.o):(.text+0x374): undefined reference to `___WSAFDIsSet@8'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(select.o):(.text+0x3b4): undefined reference to `___WSAFDIsSet@8'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(select.o):(.text+0x3d1): undefined reference to `___WSAFDIsSet@8'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(select.o):(.text+0x42f): undefined reference to `___WSAFDIsSet@8'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(select.o):(.text+0x445): more undefined references to `___WSAFDIsSet@8' follow
curl\lib/libcurl.a(select.o):(.text+0x77d): undefined reference to `_select@20'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(select.o):(.text+0x78c): undefined reference to `_WSAGetLastError@0'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(select.o):(.text+0x849): undefined reference to `___WSAFDIsSet@8'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(select.o):(.text+0x863): undefined reference to `___WSAFDIsSet@8'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(select.o):(.text+0x884): undefined reference to `___WSAFDIsSet@8'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(content_encoding.o):(.text+0x170): undefined reference to `_inflate'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(content_encoding.o):(.text+0x18c): undefined reference to `_inflateEnd'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(content_encoding.o):(.text+0x1ac): undefined reference to `_inflateInit2_'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(content_encoding.o):(.text+0x224): undefined reference to `_inflateEnd'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(content_encoding.o):(.text+0x27e): undefined reference to `_inflateEnd'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(content_encoding.o):(.text+0x294): undefined reference to `_inflateEnd'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(content_encoding.o):(.text+0x2be): undefined reference to `_inflateEnd'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(content_encoding.o):(.text+0x2ce): undefined reference to `_inflateEnd'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(content_encoding.o):(.text+0x33e): undefined reference to `_inflateInit_'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(content_encoding.o):(.text+0x472): undefined reference to `_zlibVersion'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(content_encoding.o):(.text+0x4b0): undefined reference to `_inflateInit2_'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(content_encoding.o):(.text+0x4f8): undefined reference to `_inflateInit2_'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(content_encoding.o):(.text+0x58c): undefined reference to `_inflateEnd'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(content_encoding.o):(.text+0x5c9): undefined reference to `_inflateEnd'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(content_encoding.o):(.text+0x6ca): undefined reference to `_inflateEnd'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(nonblock.o):(.text+0x2a): undefined reference to `_ioctlsocket@12'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(md5.o):(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `_MD5_Init'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(md5.o):(.text+0x3b): undefined reference to `_MD5_Update'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(md5.o):(.text+0x4e): undefined reference to `_MD5_Final'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(md5.o):(.rdata+0x0): undefined reference to `_MD5_Init'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(md5.o):(.rdata+0x4): undefined reference to `_MD5_Update'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(md5.o):(.rdata+0x8): undefined reference to `_MD5_Final'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(md5.o):(.rdata+0x14): undefined reference to `_MD5_Init'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(md5.o):(.rdata+0x18): undefined reference to `_MD5_Update'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(md5.o):(.rdata+0x1c): undefined reference to `_MD5_Final'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(curl_gethostname.o):(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `_gethostname@8'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(socks_sspi.o):(.text+0x2e4): undefined reference to `_htons@4'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(socks_sspi.o):(.text+0x427): undefined reference to `_ntohs@4'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(socks_sspi.o):(.text+0x811): undefined reference to `_htons@4'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(socks_sspi.o):(.text+0xc5c): undefined reference to `_htons@4'
curl\lib/libcurl.a(socks_sspi.o):(.text+0xd7e): undefined reference to `_ntohs@4'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Edit:** I also tried downloading the Windows OpenSSL package offered on their website and including it - no change.

**Edit:** It's finally working! The solution was to use the 32-bit cURL package and to pass these parameters to the compiler:

```
g++ -o Test.exe Test.cpp -DCURL_STATICLIB -I curl\include -L curl\lib -lcurldll -lssh2 -lidn -lrtmp -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lws2_32 -lwldap32
```

Comment: Can you post the complete output? Have you tried compiling this example `simple.c` with gcc instead of g++?

Comment: This is the complete output. And yes, I have. Exactly the same result. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Try compiling with `-v` to see more info: `g++ -v -o Test.exe ...`

Comment: Where did you get libcurl from? Have you compiled it yourself?

Comment: @Olaf Thanks for your reply. I added the output when using -v. I got libcurl from here, where I downloaded the x64 MinGW devel package.

Comment: I just noticed I screwed up the link. [Here it is.](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html)

Comment: I had massive amounts of trouble with this as well.  I found this [article](http://geographika.co.uk/64-bit-curl-with-openssl-on-windows) which helped a lot.  It's for 64 bit curl with SSL, but it might help your cause.

Comment: @Bok I managed to fix it, but thanks for your comment anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since everything is setup correctly, I see two solutions:

either remove `-DCURL_STATICLIB` or add `-static` to your command line.

**Edit:**
It took some time, but it looks like you have a 32 bit Mingw and a 64 bit libcurl. Download the 32 bit libcurl and try again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that gets me the same error message. I tried with all four combinations of -DCURL_STATICLIB and -static.
Except when removing -DCURL_STATICLIB I get `undefined reference to '__imp__curl_easy_init'` instead of `undefined reference to '_curl_easy_init'`

Comment: Great idea, I can't believe I didn't think of that...
Though I now have a lot more error messages, see main post :/

Comment: As you can see, these messages belong to libcurl. So, you're missing additional libraries to satisfy these references. Look into the `curl/lib` directory to see, wether, there are libraries you can add. Some of these messages come from missing ssl symbols. You might also try linking against the dynamic (not static) library.

Comment: It works! Finally! Thank you so much! I'll edit my main post to show my solution.